# SWI prolog- why am I getting wrong answers?

Tags: prolog

I have a simple code in SWI Prolog. I have carefully written the following code. When I ask it simple questions such as "Can sweety a fish?" or "Can Fodor swim?", I'm getting the wrong answers. Can anyone please tell me where I'm making a mistake, I have tried everything. Thank you

(Shortcut to editing my code: http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/zxufyDOz.pl)

```
motion(x,biped).
motion(x,quadruped).

spider(lobby). %Lobby is a spider
spider(x):- not(mammal(x)). %For all x, if x is a spider then x is NOT a mammal.  (Spiders are not mammals)

dog(fidora). %Fidora is a dog

fish(sweety). %Sweety is a fish
swim(x,canswim) :- fish(x).

%fish(x) :- swim(x). %For all x, if x is a fish then it can swim
%fish(x) :- not(mammal(x)). %fishes are not mammals

not(fish(x)) :- not(swim(x)). %For all x, if x is a not fish then it can’t swim

mammal(x) :- birth(x, baby). %For all x, if x is a mammal then x lays eggs or babies
mammal(x):- motion(x, biped); motion(x, quadruped). %For all x, if x is a mammal then it is either biped or quadruped

mammal(x):- dog(x). %all dogs are mammals 
mammal(x) :- platypus(x). %platypus is a mammal

birth(platypus, egg). %At least one mammal lays eggs
```

Comment: Lower case strings are atoms (constants) in Prolog. If you want to have a variable, it MUST be upper case. For example, you should have, `mammal(X) :- dog(X).` etc. `fish(sweety).` is correct, for example, because you are establishing a fact `fish` about the identifier (atom) `sweety`.

Answer (score 0):

First, can you post exact queries, where you get wrong answers? For example, what do you mean by "Can sweety a fish?"

Second, I notice arity inconsistencies with the `swim` predicate. Look at:

```
swim(x,canswim) :- fish(x).
not(fish(x)) :- not(swim(x)).
```

Mabye what you meant was just:

```
swim(x) :- fish(x).
```

?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to query the following:
(i). Can Sweety swim?
(ii) Is Fidor a mammal?
(iii) Can Fidor swim?
(iv) Is Lobby a fish?

Comment: I have tried using all the different methods, so that when I query the knowledge base: Can Sweety Swim, I get True, but I keep getting false. 
I have tried:

swim(x,canswim) :- fish(x).
fish(x) :- swim(x). %For all x, if x is a fish then it can swim
fish(x) :- not(mammal(x)). %fishes are not mammals
not(fish(x)) :- not(swim(x)). %For all x, if x is a not fish then it can’t swim

But none of it gives me the answer I want. Thank you